# How exactly do I import SearchKit?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I'm looking to give SearchKit a try for a little side project, but I'm having trouble finding out how exactly to import it. I've been hunting around online all day, and haven't found a solid example of anyone incorporating it into a project, let alone specifics of importing it.

I know that it is part of CoreServices, but simply importing that doesn't seem to give me access to SearchKit APIs. I was able to find a SearchKit.framework, but it's a MacOSX framework, not an iOS framework.

I feel like I'm missing something silly.. anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [SearchKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/search_kit) is used to provide the Spotlight search service, it is only directly accessible on macOS.

[Core Spotlight](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corespotlight) is available on macOS and iOS.